How can i fix Undo and Redo not working in Object Mode?
Undo and Redo don't work in Object Mode. How can I fix?


Found the problem increased undo memory limit 200 to 10k

The Undo Memory Limit is usually set to 0 (zero) on installation which means it is unlimited. see the Blender Manual entry.
